# mongodb $or in JAVA

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to execute the following query in java but it returns no results at all even though on command line it works fine! they are identical queries but different results!

```
    BasicDBObject m_query = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject cid = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBList in = new BasicDBList();
    in.add("56eea58b013693083806ab92");
    cid.append("client_id", new BasicDBObject("$in", in));
    BasicDBObject pcid = new BasicDBObject();
    pcid.append("parent_client_id", new BasicDBObject("$in", in));
    BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
    or.add(cid);
    or.add(pcid);
    m_query.append("$or", or);
    System.out.println(m_query);
    System.out.println(mongoTemplate().getCollection(datatType).count(m_query));
```

The printed results are:

```
>{ "$or" : [ { "client_id" : { "$in" : [ "578ac9492c1ae71f2958d2c2"]}} , { "parent_client_id" : { "$in" : [ "578ac9492c1ae71f2958d2c2"]}}]}

> 0
```

When I execute the following on mongo cmd I get "5" as result for count:

```
> db.collection.count({$or : [ {client_id: {$in : ["578ac9492c1ae71f2958d2c2"]}}, {parent_client_id: {$in : ["578ac9492c1ae71f2958d2c2"]}} ]})

> {
    "client_id": "56eea58b013693083806ab92",
    "activity_type": "client",
    "geo_tag": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            35.83278446,
            31.97517983
        ]
    },
    "cell_phone": "",
    "_platform": "web",
    "client_status": "lead",
    "phone": "",
    "name": "client 2",
    "comment": "undefined",
    "zip_extension": "",
    "contact_title": "",
    "user": "Representative"
}
```

Comment: Is the name of collection `datatType` correct?

Comment: yes same in both cmd and Java!

Comment: could you provide document structure in your collection, so it would be easier to debug your code?

Comment: I edited the question, but the thing is it works on cmd but not in java for the same query.

Comment: I tried your query, it works fine for me both with Java driver and with mongo shell. Something is wrong with your connection to the collection.

Comment: Thanks let me check